# Increase field value by 1 every minute

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to increment a Firestore field's value by 1 every minute, therefore I create a scheduled Cloud Function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const ref = db.collection('count').doc('currentTrack');

export const everyMinuteJob = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(context => {
    ref.get().then( value => {
      if (value.exists) {
        const id = value.data().id + 1;
        ref.update({ id });
      }
    });
  });
```

Deploying this code I get the following error:

> error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined':
>   const id = value.data().id + 1;

I've already tried multiple things, but they've always resolved in an error.

What's the correct approach for this behavior?

Comment: I gave you an answer for your immediate problem, but you will have another problem with the fact that you're not handling the promise returned by `ref.update()`.  That problem is unrelated to the one you face right now, but it is still a problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, I'll read into that!

Answer (score 0):

`value` is going to be a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) type object.  According to the API documentation for that, its [data()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) method can return DocumentData or undefined.  In order to satisfy strict TypeScript checks, you must check for the undefined case in order to use the returned DocumentData object.  It doesn't matter if value.event previously returned true - TypeScript doesn't draw any connection between the `exists` property and the return value of `data()`.

```
  if (value.exists) {
    const data = value.data();
    if (data) {
      // now TypeScript has a guarantee that data is not undefined
      const id = value.data().id + 1;
      ref.update({ id });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to also change `const id = value.data().id + 1;` to `const id = data.id + 1;`, but I assume you solely forgot that. Another strange thing, the initial field value was 1 - now that I add 1 ( `+ 1`) via the cloud function - it's 11.

Comment: That's because you're appending 1 to a string value.  id needs to be a number, not a string.